# Linq Queries and Cannot implicitly convert type error

Tags: asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

According to given project id(this id is coming to action as a parameter), I want to find this project and this project's issues and then I want to find some issues which has the "bug" type using linq queries in my MVC asp.net web application. But when I try below code in my action in ProjectController, I take this error: Cannot implicitly convert type `'System.Collection.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<MVCTest1.Models.Issue>>'to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MVCTest1.Models.Issue>'` and

```
        List<Issue> issueList = (from i in db.Projects where i.projectID == projectId select i.Issues).ToList();

        List<Issue> bugList = (from bug in issueList where bug. ) --> I cannot reach properties of bug issue
```

Here my project Model:

```
  public class Project
  {

    public int projectID { get; set; }

    public string projectName { get; set; }

    public string descriptionProject { get; set; }

    public Project parentProject { get; set; }

    public string identifier { get; set; }


    public DateTime date { get; set; }

    public List<Project> subProjects { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Issue> Issues { get; set; }     
  }
```

and my Issue Model:

```
 public class Issue
 {
    public int issueID { get; set; }

    public string description { get; set; }

    public string subject { get; set; }

    public IssueStatus? status { get; set; }

    public Issue parentTask { get; set; }


    public DateTime startDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime dueDate { get; set; }

    public int done { get; set; }

    public IssuePriority? priority { get; set; }

    public IssueType? type { get; set; }

    public virtual List<User> Users { get; set; }

  }
```

finally my enum:

```
public enum IssueType
{
    Bug = 0,
    Feature = 1,
    Support = 2,
    Operation = 3
}
```

Thanks in advance.

// edit 2

```
        var project = db.Projects.Single(p => p.projectID == projectId);
        var issues = project.Issues;
        var bugIssues = from bug in issues where bug.type == 0 select bug;
        return PartialView(bugIssues);
```

When I write this I got this error :

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereListIterator`1[MVCTest1.Models.Issue]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MVCTest1.Models.Issue]'.

Comment: You try to add a `List<Issue>` as an item in `List<Issue>`. Your item you retrieve with the LINQ query is already a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `Issues` property is *already* a `List<Issue>`. I suspect you want something like:

```
// TODO: Fix property naming...
var project = db.Projects.Single(p => p.projectId == projectId);
var issues = project.Issues;
```

Now `issues` will be a `List<Issue>` rather than a `List<List<Issue>>`.

EDIT: For the next problem, you've got an `IEnumerable<Issue>` but you're expecting a `List<Issue>`, so you need to call `ToList()` at *that* point. For example:

```
var project = db.Projects.Single(p => p.projectId == projectId);
return PartialView(project.Issues.Where(b => b.type == 0).ToList());
```

Comment: I can use now issues object but                                   The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereListIterator`1[BulguTakipSistemiv3.Models.Issue]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[BulguTakipSistemiv3.Models.Issue]'. error occured.

Comment: @melomg: Then you need to call `ToList` on those results, e.g. `return PartialView(bugIssues.ToList());`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the expected model of the MVC view, it expects a `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`, but you gave a `System.Linq.Enumerable`.

Try do this.

```
return PartialView(bugIssues.ToList());
```